# Counting rows from table after joins

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query that selects data from 4 tables via joins, i want to also count the number rows in a fifth table containing a matching foreign key.

This is what my current query looks look like, and it doesnt work

```
"SELECT 
                     ph.pheed_id,ph.user_id,ph.datetime,ph.repheeds,
                     ph.pheed,fav.id,fav.P_id,fav.datetime as stamp,
                     u.username,ava.avatar_small
                     COUNT(pheed_comments.comment_id) as comments
                     FROM favourite_pheeds fav
                     INNER JOIN pheeds ph ON ph.pheed_id=fav.P_id
                     INNER JOIN users u ON u.id=ph.user_id
                     INNER JOIN profiles pr ON pr.user_id=ph.user_id
                     LEFT JOIN user_avatars ava ON ava.avatar_id=pr.avatar
                     ORDER BY stamp DESC
                     LIMIT $offset,$limit";
```

How do i count the number rows in a fifth table containing a matching foreign key.

Comment: If you want to find the matching count from fifth table then use INNER JOIN.

Comment: What do you mean with doesn't work? Do you get an syntax error? Or is your result empty?

Comment: @rekire yeah i get a syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select ph.pheed_id,
    ph.user_id,
    ph.datetime,
    ph.repheeds,
    ph.pheed,
    fav.id,
    fav.P_id,
    fav.datetime as stamp,
    u.username,
    ava.avatar_small,
    coalesce(pcc.Count, 0) as comments_count
from favourite_pheeds fav
inner join pheeds ph on ph.pheed_id = fav.P_id
inner join users u on u.id = ph.user_id
inner join profiles pr on pr.user_id = ph.user_id
left join user_avatars ava on ava.avatar_id = pr.avatar
left outer join (
    select pheed_id, count(*) as Count
    from pheed_comments
    group by pheed_id --took a guess at the column name here
) pcc on ph.pheed_id = pcc.pheed_id
order by stamp desc 
LIMIT $offset, $limit
```